# Links not Routing with Bootstrap React NavBar Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

App.JS

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div>
            <HeaderComponent />
            <Switch>
              <Route exactly component={HomePage} pattern="/" />
              <Route exactly component={ContactUs} pattern="/contact"/>
              
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Navbar built from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

```
  return (

                        <Navbar className="textCenter" style={NavBarStyles} bg="white" variant="light" margin="auto">
                            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                            </Nav>
                            
                            
                        </Navbar>
   
            
        );
```

I was able to get the functionality I want when I scrapped the Bootstrap Navbar and simply used an ul with the "Link to..." syntax.

But I quite like my navbar and I can't seem to find how to apply that functionality I had with Link to.. Each time I click the link nothing happens whatsoever, I've tried using the href class, using to="/link" but still nothing happens.

To be more clear, I want to click a link and render a different page. Right now I click the link and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `as` prop to retain Bootstrap styles but use `react-router-dom`'s `Link`

```
<Nav.Link to="/" as={Link}>Home</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Doing that as well as changing
       
<Route exactly component={ContactUs} pattern="/contact"/>

To 
<Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactUs} />

Fixed my issue